# configuration is still incorrect in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

When I just want to run my simple beginner java program, the IntelliJ tell me that "configuration is still incorrect, Do you want to edit it again". I've read the official web of IntelliJ about set up configuration, but I don't think it give me helps. My computer is macOS with version 10.14.6; the IntelliJ version is 2021.2.3 community edition. I'll post my configuration setting, can anyone tell me where I set my configuration wrong?

My second question is that: When I want to run a specific file by right click my current java file and choose run xxx, IntelliJ will run all the fills under my current directory. How can I only run a single fill that I want to run?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no "Main class" defined in your Run Configuration. Please choose a class that has `public static void main(String[] args)` function inside

Comment: My class contains a main function, and I'm still having issues.